# How do i make this ruby view code more readable and DRY?

Tags: ruby, haml

I've encountered a rather complex view in a sinatra app. How would you go about refactoring this mess?

```
.central
  %ul
    %li
      - selected = is_sub ? "": "selected"
      %a{:href => '/' + section + '/index.html', :class => selected}
        1
    -navigation.each_index do |primary_idx|
      -primary_hash  = navigation[primary_idx]
      -primary_token = primary_hash[:rewrite] || convert_to_url_token(primary_hash[:title])
      -if url_match?(primary_token)
        -primary_hash[:children].each_with_index do |secondary_hash, secondary_idx|
          %li
            -secondary_token = secondary_hash[:rewrite] || convert_to_url_token(secondary_hash[:title])
            %a{:href => '/' + section + '/' + secondary_token + '/index.html', :class => url_match?(secondary_token) ? "selected" : ""}
              =secondary_idx + 2
%p
  -navigation.each_index do |primary_idx|
    -primary_hash  = navigation[primary_idx]
    -primary_token = primary_hash[:rewrite] || convert_to_url_token(primary_hash[:title])
    -if url_match?(primary_token)
      -primary_hash[:children].each_with_index do |secondary_hash, secondary_idx|
        -secondary_token = secondary_hash[:rewrite] || convert_to_url_token(secondary_hash[:title])
        -if url_match?(secondary_token) || !is_sub
          page
          -current_page = is_sub ? secondary_idx + 2 : 1
          =current_page
          \/
          =primary_hash[:children].size + 1
          -break
```

Comment: Personally I find something like this pretty haha. Favorite-ing  this after it gets refactored. I am interested in seeing how this turns out.

Comment: I love it when i encounter something like this. Like a pig in shit. So many opportunities to refactor. I would write a presenter.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things:

- `navigation.each_index` should just become `navigation.each`. You're not using the index separately.
- `primary_token` should be defined as a method on the `navigation` model so you're not cluttering up the view with it. The same probably goes form the `if url_match?` blocks.
- In Rails, you could refactor some of the looping into partials. I don't know if Sinatra supports something similar.
- The `selected` and `current_page` stuff should probably be set in the controller, though I don't know enough about your logic flow to say for sure.

Basically, your views should get all the data they need either through variables set in the controller or through simple method calls on those variables (that is, something like `variable.some_property`, not the monstrosities you have here). That usually means you have to write more methods on your models to support this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what this code is trying to accomplish because it's not clear to me what any of the variables are set to. I *think* it's trying to do multilevel nav. Here's a bit of refactoring I might do to accomplish *that* goal.

#### view

```
- section_selected = is_sub? ? "": "selected"
.central
  %ul
    %li= link_to section.name, "/#{section.url}/index.html", :class => section_selected

    - section.subsections.each do |subsection_item|
      - subsection_selected = url_match? subsection.url
      %li= link_to subsection.name, "/#{section.url}/#{subsection.url}/index.html", :class => subsection_selected
```

#### presenter class beginning

```
class Section
  attr_accessible :name, :url, :subsections
end
```

#### some controller/model

```
sections = [].tap do |s|
  s << Section.new(:name => "foo", :url => "bar")
  s << Section.new(:name => "x", 
                   :url => y, 
                   :subsections => [
                                    Section.new(:name => "sub", :url => "omg")
                                   ])
end
```